# Generalized creation and annihilation operators (for bounded operators)

Tags: functional-analysis, mathematical-physics, spectral-theory, quantum-mechanics

I'm currently reading [this paper of Marcel Griesemer](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.00395) about the
Dirac-Frenkel-approximation method for so-called polarons. It is a mathematical
paper and I'm currently confused with a certain notation he establishes:

In Section 6, page 6, he defines the Hilbert-space $\mathcal{H} =
L^2(\mathbb{R}^d) \otimes \mathcal{F}$, where $\mathcal{F}$ is the symmetric
Fock space over $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathrm{d} k)$. Then -- everything is fine so far --
he defines $a(f)$ and $a^\ast(f)$ to be the creation and annhilation operators
on the Fock space $\mathcal{F}$ with respect to a function $f\in
L^2(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathrm{d} k)$.

Here comes the confusing sentence:

> It is useful and convenient to extend the notions of creation and
>   annihilation operators to include operators $a^\ast(G)$ and $a(G)$ in
>   $\mathcal{H}$, where the map $k \mapsto G(k)$ takes values in the
>   bounded operators on the particle space $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$.

There is no explanation on how exactly these operators are defined, how they
act, whatsoever.
I would be glad if someone could specify this notion to me.